# Filtering out Numpy values through Indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, filter

The code below is supposed to look at the I am trying to write a code where it filters through the indexes and checks if `unix_val, unix_val2` are equivalent and then gets the indexes where they are equivalent. Filters the `val,val2` arrays. Then also checks if they are equivalent and returns the indexes where it is `True`. How would i be able to fix the code down below and get the Expected Output.

```
import numpy as np 

a=np.array(["Short","Long","Short","Long","Short","Long"])
b=np.array(["Short","Long","Short","Long"])
c=np.array(["Short","Long","Short","Long","Long","Long"])

unix_a=np.array([1624580882,1624584458,1624589467,1624592213,1624595336,1624596349])
unix_b=np.array([1624580882,1624584458,1624595336,1624596349])
unix_c=np.array([1624580882,1624584464,1624589495,1624592238,1624595350,1624596380])

def Compare(val,val2, unix_val, unix_val2):

    unix_comparison= np.where(unix_val= unix_val2,unix_val2)
    unix_index = np.where(unix_val= unix_comparison)
    val = val[unix_index]
    val2 = val2[unix_index]
    val_Comparison = np.where(val= val2)
    return val_Comparison 

Compare(a, b, unix_a, unix_b)
Compare(a, c, unix_a, unix_c)
```

Error Output:

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Expected output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 5]
[0]
```

Comment: `np.where(unix_val= unix_val2,unix_val2)` <= positional argument follows keyword argument. I guess you meant to write `unix_val==unix_val2`

Comment: that still reproduces an error : `ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given`

Comment: That also means exactly what it says. Overall, it looks the first two lines should be just `unix_index = np.where(unix_val==unix_val2)`